# How to find average, Max and largest(similar to excel function) in a list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list of numbers and from this list, I want to create 3 more lists that contain the maximum, average, and 5th largest number from it. My original list `overdraw` is the block of lists, which means it has sub-blocks in it and each block has 6 numbers in it and there are a total of 3 blocks or 6x3 matrix or array.

```
overdraw:
[[16,13,23,14,33,45],[23,11,54,34,23,76],[22,54,34,43,41,11]]
```

I know how to calculate max, average and 5 largest in this list. But I want a answer in a specific way like I know the max, average, and 5th largest values of each block but I want them to get printed 4 times. I know all the values:

```
Max = [45, 76, 54] 
Average = [24, 37, 34]
Largest(5th) = [14, 23, 22]
```

my approach:

```
overdraw = [[16,13,23,14,33,45],[23,11,54,34,23,76],[22,54,34,43,41,11]]

x = [sorted(block, reverse=True) for block in overdraw] # first sort the whole list

max = [x[i][0] for i in range(0, len(x))] # for max 
largest = [x[i][4] for i in range(0, len(x))] #5th largest
average = [sum(x[i])/len(x[i]) for i in range(0, len(x))] #average

print("max: ", max)
print("5th largest: ", largest)
print("average: ", average)
```

You will get the same output after running this code but I want output in this format:

```
Average = [24, 24, 24, 24, 37, 37, 37, 37, 34, 34, 34, 34] 

Max = [45, 45, 45, 45, 76, 76, 76, 76, 54, 54, 54, 54]     

Largest(5th) = [14, 14, 14, 14, 23, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22, 22, 22]
```

As you can see each average, max, and the largest number is printed 4 times in their respective list. So can anyone help with this answer?

Comment: Are you expecting a dataframe output?

Comment: no. Just in a list or a NumPy array because I want to use this for further calculations.

Comment: but your expected output looks like a dataframe. Can you modify expected output?

Comment: Yeah I know it looks like a DataFrame but that was just for the better visual.

Comment: @nipun do you know what a dataframe (pandas) actually is ? You can do all the calculations you want with those.

Comment: I have some rough idea about that. But yes I am learning that.

Comment: Also your example of output makes no sens. What about making one that really looks like what you want.. We can guess what you want.. But guessing is not the idea here..

Comment: Yeah I have edited my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that returns lists like you specified

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

n_times = 4

overdraw = [[16,13,23,14,33,45],[23,11,54,34,23,76],[22,54,34,43,41,11]]
y = [sorted(block, reverse=True) for block in overdraw]

maximum = list(itertools.chain(*[[max(x)]*n_times for x in y]))
average = list(itertools.chain(*[[int(round(sum(x)/len(x)))]*n_times for x in y]))
fifth_largest = list(itertools.chain(*[[x[4]]*n_times for x in y]))

print(f"Average = {average}")
print(f"Max = {maximum}")
print(f"Largest(5th): {fifth_largest}")
```

Outputs:

```
Average = [24, 24, 24, 24, 37, 37, 37, 37, 34, 34, 34, 34]
Max = [45, 45, 45, 45, 76, 76, 76, 76, 54, 54, 54, 54]
Largest(5th): [14, 14, 14, 14, 23, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22, 22, 22]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's actually the answer in the exact way that I wanted it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'OvIdx'       : 3 * [range(4)],
    'Average'     : average,
    'Max'         : max,  # should be renamed/assigned as max_ instead
    'Largest(5th)': largest
}).explode('OvIdx').set_index('OvIdx').astype(int)
print(df)
```

which shows

```
       Average  Max  Largest(5th)
OvIdx                            
0           24   45            14
1           24   45            14
2           24   45            14
3           24   45            14
0           36   76            23
1           36   76            23
2           36   76            23
3           36   76            23
0           34   54            22
1           34   54            22
2           34   54            22
3           34   54            22
```

from here, you can still do all the calculations you want and/or getting a NumPy array, doing `df.values`.

---

Following your comment, you can also get your column(s) as individual entities, doing, e.g.

```
>>> df.Average.tolist()
[24, 24, 24, 24, 36, 36, 36, 36, 34, 34, 34, 34]

>>> df.Max.tolist()
[45, 45, 45, 45, 76, 76, 76, 76, 54, 54, 54, 54]

>>> df['Largest(5th)'].tolist()  # as string key since the name is a little bit exotic
[14, 14, 14, 14, 23, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22, 22, 22]
```

which approach starts to be a little bit overkilled, readable though.

Comment: @nipunvats better now ?

Comment: Thank you so much. You just motivated me more to learn about pandas. Thanks a lot

Comment: Definitely, you should really have a look at Pandas. In Python, it is the library to master for data scientists.